# How to find the difference of max & min values in one group in a variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, grouping

I have three variables A, B & C in the following format

```
A         B     C
Cat1      1    NA       
Cat1      2    NA
Cat1      1    NA
Cat1      2    NA
Cat1      NA   4
Cat1      NA   1
Cat1      NA   6
Cat1      NA   4
Cat1      7    NA       
Cat1      9    NA
Cat1      3    NA
Cat1      2    NA
Cat1      NA   2
Cat1      NA   4 
Cat1      NA   5
Cat1      NA   9
.         .    .
.         .    .        
.         .    .
.         .    .
```

lets say in variable C wherever there are numerical values part from NA, it should be called as one Group and I have to find the difference of maximum & minimum values in that group..Can someone please help

desired Output:

Sure. The desired output be like : A      Trips     Value

```
                              Cat 1   Trip1      xx (dif of max & min of that trip)
```

Comment: Can you post a desired output for the data posted?

Comment: Can you please give more clarity? What do you mean by 'one Group'? An example of what you expect to see will help

Comment: what about: `max(df$C[!is.na(C)]) - min(df$C[!is.na(C)])`

Comment: Sure. The desired output be like : A        Group       Value

                                                    Cat 1   Group1    xx (dif of max & min)   ...when I say group there are multiple such instances or iterations where there are some values followed by NA's followed by values etc...so I want to identify those values as multiple groups & for each group I need a difference in max & min value of that group. I dont know if my explanation is clear :( please let me know if not i will try more..

Comment: definition of groups not completely clear

Comment: okay just treat them as multiple trips...instead of group just treat them as Trip1, Trip2.. etc...

Comment: modified desired output..please take a look & let me know if you have any questions...

Comment: Is trip1 from row 1 to row 8?

Comment: yes trip 1 is from row  1 to row 8 but I need difference in max & min only from values of c from row 5 to row 8

Comment: @Uday Could you comment on the provided solutions? If either solved your issue please consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: I just did.. kindly scroll down  & let me know your thoughts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(trip = cumsum(is.na(C))) %>%
  drop_na(C) %>%
  mutate(trip = group_indices(., trip)) %>%
  group_by(trip) %>%
  summarize(Diff = max(C) - min(C)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    trip  Diff
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     5
# 2     2     7
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A         B     C
Cat1      1    NA       
                  Cat1      2    NA
                  Cat1      1    NA
                  Cat1      2    NA
                  Cat1      NA   4
                  Cat1      NA   1
                  Cat1      NA   6
                  Cat1      NA   4
                  Cat1      7    NA       
                  Cat1      9    NA
                  Cat1      3    NA
                  Cat1      2    NA
                  Cat1      NA   2
                  Cat1      NA   4 
                  Cat1      NA   5
                  Cat1      NA   9",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank You but what if I have multiple categories or cars...presently the above logic is for only 1 category(Cat1)..what if I have more in my data...please advise

Comment: @Uday You can add `A` to the `group_by` command like `group_by(A, trip)`.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, lets say if I have another column or variable called time stamp (eg: 2018-05-01 00:34:21.728) how can I have one time stamp for the entire trip? I am okay with having the time stamp captured by the end of each trip.. please advise. Thanks again

Comment: @Uday This way of communication is inefficient. If my answer solved your original question, please accept it and then post a new question. In the new question, please include a reproducible example with all the relevant details, such as group, trip, time stamp, and the desired output.

Comment: Sure. Agreed! Thanks

Comment: @Uday In case you don't know how to accept an answer, here is an explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Whether to accept or not to accept is completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for educating me...I just did :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you could do the following

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(text)
dt[, .(C = diff(range(C))), by = .(grp = rleid(is.na(C)))]
#   grp  C
#1:   1 NA
#2:   2  5
#3:   3 NA
#4:   4  7
```

For `B` and `C` at the same time do

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(range(x))), by = .(grp = rleid(is.na(C))), .SDcols = c('B', 'C')]
#   grp  B  C
#1:   1  1 NA
#2:   2 NA  5
#3:   3  7 NA
#4:   4 NA  7
```

Another option to remove the `NA`s

```
cols <- c('B', 'C')
out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(range(x))), by = rleid(is.na(C)), .SDcols = cols
          ][, lapply(.SD, na.omit), .SDcols = cols
            ][, grp := rleid(B)]
out
#   B C grp
#1: 1 5   1
#2: 7 7   2
```

Note that the second and third solutions assumes that `B` is `NA` when `C` is not et vice versa.

**data**

```
text <- "A         B     C
Cat1      1    NA       
Cat1      2    NA
Cat1      1    NA
Cat1      2    NA
Cat1      NA   4
Cat1      NA   1
Cat1      NA   6
Cat1      NA   4
Cat1      7    NA       
Cat1      9    NA
Cat1      3    NA
Cat1      2    NA
Cat1      NA   2
Cat1      NA   4 
Cat1      NA   5
Cat1      NA   9"
```

Comment: Dear markus, I am still trying to comprehend your solution as the desired output should be inline to user www has created.. i need output as below  Cartype Trip no Value
Cat1      1    23

Cat1      2    34

Cat1      3    12

Cat2      1    18

Cat2      2    19

Cat2      3    23

Comment: Awesome, It worked.. I added cat/car variable as well in groupby.. Thanks a lot :)